# Android background image that does cover the upper screen

Tags: android

I hope I am facing a development issue. Not an art issue.

I am trying to develop a UI like the one shown below.

[image: denko original]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/welcome_bg_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/welcome_bg_image" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mm_flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mm_flag" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/welcome_rectangle"
        android:id="@+id/rectangular_orange"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/welcome_bg_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="-130dp"
        android:clickable="true">
        <org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.denko.customui.MyanmarTextView
            android:id="@+id/welcome_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:text="@string/welcome"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/welcome_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:text="@string/forward_arrow"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
        <org.bitbucket.infovillafoundation.denko.customui.MyanmarTextView
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/welcome_text"
            android:layout_below="@id/welcome_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            android:text="@string/denko_welcome_text"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/welcome_bg_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/denko_logo"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

What I get is the one shown below.

[image: denko mine]

I attempted to set `scaleType` to `fitXY` but the result an overstretched image. What can I do if I want a background image the fits the upper part of the screen but do not want the image to be stretched unproportionally. I also want cropping to occur if stretching the image does not leave a space for the lower part.

Comment: try `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`, if it still shows smaller than the screen then maybe you should make the image for different resolutions

Comment: I've also tried `centerCrop`. Maybe it's time to start recreating images.